# Rails - how to move view logic into a helper when iterating through an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in my view, I am displaying the prices for Shirts, which belong to a Products category. In my view, I am currently looking through an array of shirts like so:

```
<% @shirts.get_shirts("red", "small").each do |shirt| %>
  <%= shirt.price ">
<% end %>
```

This works just like I want, displaying only the prices for shirts that are red and small.

However, when I try to move this logic into the corresponding helper, it displays the full object data instead of just the prices. My helper code is below:

```
def show_prices(color, size)
@shirts.get_shirts(color, size).each do |shirt|
  shirt.price
end
end
```

and I calling it in the view like so:

```
<%= show_prices("red","small") %>
```

What am I doing wrong in the helper? It seems like it should just do the same thing but it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Result of `each` method is collection. Probably you want next helper method

```
def show_prices(color, size)
  @shirts.get_shirts(color, size).map(&:price).join
end
```